# fitting steering wheel controls to polo mk5

Tags: vw, audio, steering-wheel, polo

Does anyone know if you can get aftermarket steering wheel controls fitted for my 2012 Polo?  Knowing VW it'll be a gazillion pounds if it is even an option. By fitted I mean actually integrated and not strapped onto the steering wheel.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to add a MFSW (Multi Function Steering Wheel) or, depending on the design of your steering wheel, add just the buttons and control module.  It will require some research and some scouring of ebay and some VW forums.

On some late model Volkswagen cars, you can add a Golf GTI steering wheel and then fit the following parts;

**5K0 953 549 B** (electronic control module on steering column for my(model year)2011 models. The std. **5K0 953 549 C** is not enough)

**5K0 998 537 B** (MF buttons plate)

**5K0 971 584 A** (airbag cable)

**5K0 959 542** (control module INSIDE the steering wheel)

Once you've fitted these you need to adjust some settings in your ECU to switch on the control module and surpress any errors that may be generated by the wiper stalks.

You may additionally need a wiring harness.  These are vehicle year specific and there is some confusion about which is required for which model.

**5k0 953 569 K** (which has been now replaced with **5k0 953 569 G**).

the module **1K0 953 549 CD** should be ok for cars up to my2010.

module **5k0 953 569 G** may or may not be for my2011.

This is not the definitive parts list but should be a good starting point.  I've personally not fitted them as my 2012 Golf came from the factory with a MFSW.

One note about my (model year) on Volkswagen.  It runs from Sept / Oct so my 2003 Bora is a my2004 car.  You can decode the sticker in the boot to establish the full model year of your car.  You can actually work out the day on which it was built from that sticker.

I'd start my further research [here](http://forums.vwvortex.com/showthread.php?5002442-Adding-MFSW-Buttons-to-Base-2011-GTI) and maybe take a look at some threads on clubpolo.  Good luck.